# Wait until element exist but only run code once

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am currently using the following code to execute my jQuery. However, as you can see I have set some timers on executing the second part of the code. What I would like is to see if #objectPrice exists, and then run the timed code but only once. This way I can replace the timers.

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if (jQuery('#objectPrice').length) {
     var content = jQuery('#prisen').html();
     objectPrice.value = content.replace(/\D/g,'');
   }
}, 200); // check every 200ms

setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#downPayment").focus(); }, 2200);
setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#downPayment").blur(); }, 2205);
```

Comment: What's creating `#objectPrice`?  Likely to be much simpler to hook into that; looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: Can you identify the parent container?

Answer (score 1):

**The right way to do it**
You can do this by observing the direct parent of the element you want to check, let's assume that your element will be added to the page in the following div:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div>child 1</div>
    <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

You will need to observe any new child added to the `#parent-div` and trigger a function when this happens:

```
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if( mutation.addedNodes.length > 0){
            for(let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                let jqueryNode = jQuery(node);
                if(jqueryNode.is('#objectPrice')){
                    var content = jQuery('#prisen').html();
                    objectPrice.value = content.replace(/\D/g,'');
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(jQuery('#parent-div')[0], {childList: true});
```

---

But if you don't want to change your current code, you make it recursive and call it the first time, like the following:

```
var checkingFunction = function () {
    if(jQuery('#objectPrice').length){
        var content = jQuery('#prisen').html();
        objectPrice.value = content.replace(/\D/g,'');
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() { checkingFunction() }, 200);
    }
}

checkingFunction();
```